# Filter dataframe in one Excel worksheet and export to another Excel worksheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new at coding and would like to do the following:

I had a large dataset in an Excel file, all in one worksheet. Lets say the different columns are: **Brand**, **Country**, **City**, **Store_Number**

I want to filter the dataset above but the different brands there are, and then export the filtered dataframe on to a new Excel worksheet. I want to cycle through this and do it for all the Brands - let's say there is a very large number of unique brands in that column.

What I've used so far is:

```
df = pd.read_excel("TestFile.xlsx")

brands = df['Brand'].unique().tolist()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("MyData.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

for mybrand in brands:
    mydf = df.loc[df.Brand==mybrand]
    mydf.to_excel(writer, sheetname==mybrand)

writer.save()
```

But the error I keep getting is: sheetname is not defined

Could someone help? Stack Overflow has been so helpful when learning to code!

Comment: isn't it `sheet_name`?

Answer (score 2):

Per the pandas documentation, to_excel can take the parameters:

```
DataFrame.to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, header=True, index=True, index_label=None, startrow=0, startcol=0, engine=None, merge_cells=True, encoding=None, inf_rep='inf', verbose=True, freeze_panes=None)
```

you're trying to use
  `mydf.to_excel(writer, sheetname==mybrand)`

It should be
`mydf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=mybrand)`

Comment: Thank you @ambitiousdonut, I didn't realize both my syntax (sheet_name vs sheetname) was incorrect as well as "==" vs "="